# How to recompile ImageMagick on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and have Apache2 with Php7. When I do `php -v`
it gives me:

```
PHP 7.1.0-5+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 (cli) ( NTS )
```

When I do `convert -version`, it gives me:

```
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.4-3 Q16 x86_64 2017-01-12 http://www.imagemagick.org
```

php-imagick is already the newest version (3.4.3~rc1-4+deb.sury.org~xenial+1).

But `phpinfo()` gives me:

```
ImageMagick 6.8.9-9 Q16 x86_64 2016-11-29 http://www.imagemagick.org
```

What should I do to upgrade ImageMagick?